# Updating Column B Value with Clumn A Old Value

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, plsqldeveloper

Created the following VendorAccount Table

```
VendorAccount

(Ven_AccountId, 
  Ven_RegNo,   
  Ven_Invoice_RefNo,    
  TotalAmount,
  Paid_ToVen ,    
  Balance
)
```

In the above table the value of TotalAmount is came from another Table(`Vendor_InvoiceDetails`).The TOTALBALANCE value is selected through POPUP LOV.

The `Pad_TOVEN` amount is subtracted from `TOTALAMOUNT`(`TotalAMount-Pad_TOVEN`).When ever i select `TOTALAMOUNT` it gives me the old `TOTAL VALUE` as shown below in picture.
[image]

I want the updated the value.When ever i select TotalAmount it should give me the new updated value on the basis of `Ven_Invoice_RefNo` i-e 2300 in `TotalAmount` Column in new entry. Below is the trigger but it has the fallowing error

ERROR:   `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following: begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current curs`

Trigger:

```
create or replace trigger "VENDORACCOUNT_T2"
BEFORE
insert or update or delete on "VENDORACCOUNT"
for each row
begin
DECLARE new_balance INT; 
DECLARE new_total INT;
DECLARE new_paid INT;

   SELECT balance INTO old_balance,
   total INTO old_total,
       PAID_TOVEN INTO new_paid
   FROM vendoraccount
   WHERE ven_regno = new.ven_regno
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;

   UPDATE vendoraccount SET TOTALAMOUNT = old_total + old_balance - new_paid,
   balance = TOTALAMOUNT - new_paid
   WHERE VEN_REGNO= new.VEN_REGNO
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are five things to be done as far as I see:

1. Move begin below "declare" lines.
2. Use just one "declare" keyword.
3. Declare old_balance.
4. Declare old_total.
5. Just one "into".

   ```
   create or replace trigger "VENDORACCOUNT_T2"
   BEFORE
   insert or update or delete on "VENDORACCOUNT"
   for each row
   DECLARE new_balance INT; 
           new_total INT;
           new_paid INT;
           old_balance INT;
           old_total INT;
   begin

   SELECT balance, total, PAID_TOVEN 
   INTO old_balance, old_total, new_paid
   FROM vendoraccount
   WHERE ven_regno = new.ven_regno
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;

   UPDATE vendoraccount SET TOTALAMOUNT = old_total + old_balance - new_paid,
   balance = TOTALAMOUNT - new_paid
   WHERE VEN_REGNO= new.VEN_REGNO
   AND VEN_INVOICE_REFNO = new.VEN_INVOICE_REFNO;
   end;
   ```

Comment: LINE 8:Position 43: PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
                   LINE 8:Position 4: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Answer (score 0):

You should move the declaration section before 'begin'

Comment: @MuhammadUsman:I dint see any declaration `old_total`,now what is old_balance here .And In oracle select will be like `select x,y into v_x,v_y from ...`

Comment: @Shepherdess i get the same error when i move the declaration section before begin